# Stylesheet that replaces some elements but keeps remaining XML document completely intact

Tags: tomcat, xslt

I am using the following XSLT stylesheet for removing all `Connector`s from `server.xml`, i.e. a Tomcat configuration file, and replacing them with a new one. It works well enough (with `xsltproc`), except that the transformations won't preserve comments, etc. (These elements should be redundant, as far as `server.xml` is concerned.)

How can I modify the stylesheet so that it keeps all nodes (including comments, texts, processing instructions, etc.) faithfully intact, except for the intended changes to `Connector`s?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="/ | * | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Service">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::Connector)] | @*"/>
      <Connector/>  <!-- actual new attributes removed for brevity -->
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I modify the stylesheet so that it keeps all nodes (including
>   comments, texts, processing instructions, etc.) faithfully intact,
>   except for the intended changes

Replace this part:

```
  <xsl:template match="/ | * | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="* | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

with the standard [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```